# How do I remove _ Character(0) _ Character(0) from column header in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a df in R and the **column headers** are getting   `_ character(0) _ character(0)` values too. I want to replace/remove them either with "NA" or "" so that I can **trimws()** to remove the spaces. How would I do that?

```
|S.no|A _ character(0) _ character(0)|B _character(0) _ character(0)| 
|:---|:-----------------------------|:----------------------------|
|1   | 20                           |55                           |
|2   | 30                           |56                           |
```

I tried `colnames(df) <- gsub(" _ character(0)_ character(0)","",colnames(df))`  so that I can trim the space later to just get the column header as

```
|S.no|A|B|
|:---|:|:|
```

But I'm still getting the same characters in the header.

Comment: `fixed = TRUE` to disable regex. `gsub(" _ character(0)_ character(0)", "", colnames(df), fixed = TRUE)`.

Comment: @ 
sindri_baldur Post your comment as answer to share good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape this character to make it work: `(`

```
df <- data.frame(`A _ character(0)_ character(0)` = 1, 
                 check.names = F)
df
```

> 

```
  A _ character(0)_ character(0)
1                              1
```

> 

```
colnames(df) <- gsub(" _ character\\(0)_ character\\(0)", "", colnames(df))

df
```

> 

```
  A
1 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working great. Exactly what I was looking for on top of being easy to understand.